# Python Min() across dataframe columns with columns dtype as period['M']

Tags: python, pandas, min

I am trying to find out minimum (non-missing) value across columns and Columns has dtype as .period['M']. I have used code as: df[['p1','p2','p3']].min(axis=1) , but results are not as expected.

Input Dataframe:

```
p1 p2 p3
NaT NaT '2019-10'
NaT '2018-04' '2019-01'
NaT '2019-10' '2019-11'
'2017-01' '2018-12' '2016-12'
```

Desired Output:

```
p1 p2 p3 min_p
NaT NaT '2019-10' '2019-10'
NaT '2018-04' '2019-01' '2018-04'
NaT '2019-10' '2019-11' '2019-10'
'2017-01' NaT '2016-12' '2016-12'
```

The DDL to generate Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'p1': ['','','2019-10'],
                 'p2': ['','2018-04','2019-01'],
                 'p3': ['2017-01','','2016-12']})
df['p1'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['p1'],format='%Y-%m'),freq='M')
df['p2'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['p2'],format='%Y-%m'),freq='M')
df['p3'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['p3'],format='%Y-%m'),freq='M')
```

I tried:

```
df['min_p'] = df[['p1','p2','p3']].min(axis=1,skipna=True)
```

I am getting results as (why skina isn't working???):
min_p
inf
inf
2016-12

Pandas Version: '1.0.1'

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like bug, possible solution with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove `NaN`s and reshape and `min` per first level (index values of original):

```
df['min_p'] = df[['p1','p2','p3']].stack().min(level=0)
print (df)
        p1       p2       p3    min_p
0      NaT      NaT  2017-01  2017-01
1      NaT  2018-04      NaT  2018-04
2  2019-10  2019-01  2016-12  2016-12
```

Comment: Yep.  I agree.  Looks like a bug.

Comment: Hmmm, this might even be an issue somewhere with `numpy`. `numpy` *almost* works but I still can't figure out why some rows are problematic. `df.to_numpy().min(axis=1)` somehow works for the 1st and 3rd row but gets `NaN` for the middle one.

Comment: Thanks jezrael! So its a bug, I been trying with different ways since morning, but no luck. Thanks again!